# SQL-запрос для вывода списка сотрудников из городов с коллегами

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо вывести список сотрудников, которые работают не в одиночку (т. е больше одного сотрудника на город) и зарабатывают более 500$ ?

[image: Таблица]

Мой код:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (Id INT PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, City TEXT, Salary INT);
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (1, 'John Smith', 'New York', '1000');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (2, 'Paul Black',  'London', '600');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (3, 'Robert Johnson', 'Boston', '700');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (4, 'William O’Dell', 'Moscow', '850');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (5, 'Lisa Connors', 'New York', '1400');
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (6, 'Scott Rodgers', 'Moscow', '800');

SELECT distinct City, Name, salary, count (*)AS COUNT
FROM Employees
where Salary>'500'
group by City
```

Comment: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\`Name\` SEPARATOR ', ') \`names\`, \`City\` FROM  \`Employees\` WHERE \`Salary\` > 500 GROUP BY \`City\` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Тип данных столбца `TEXT` лучше не использовать. Это устарело (deprecated).

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Name] VARCHAR(30), City VARCHAR(30), Salary INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl ([Name], City, Salary) VALUES 
('John Smith', 'New York', '1000'),
('Paul Black',  'London', '600'),
('Robert Johnson', 'Boston', '700'),
('William O’Dell', 'Moscow', '850'),
('Lisa Connors', 'New York', '1400'),
('Scott Rodgers', 'Moscow', '800');
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT City, Name, salary, cnt = COUNT(NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY City)
    FROM @tbl
    WHERE Salary > 500
)
SELECT * FROM rs
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

**Результат**

| City | Name | salary | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Moscow | William O’Dell | 850 | 2 |
| Moscow | Scott Rodgers | 800 | 2 |
| New York | Lisa Connors | 1400 | 2 |
| New York | John Smith | 1000 | 2 |

Comment: Thank you so much)

Comment: Рад слышать, что предложенное решение работает для вас. Пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить его как ответ.